# GWT editor driver remains dirty

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am using gwt editor drivers. After calling the `flush()` method and postprocessing the data I am moving back to the same view. I have taken care that the driver is initialized and resource binding has been done. However, if I check the `IsDirty()` flag it still shows to be true. How is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Flushing doesn't clear dirty flags, setting a new value (via edit()) does.

This makes sense when you think about errors - the editor errors should not be reported by editors to their delegates except during flush to avoid double-reporting the same errors, so after flushing errors must be collected. If everything was clean at that time, this wouldn't be possible.

From `BaseEditorDriver`:

```
protected void doEdit(T object) {
  checkEditor();
  object = delegate.ensureMutable(object);
  this.object = object;
  delegate.setObject(object);
  accept(createInitializerVisitor());
  DirtCollector c = new DirtCollector();
  accept(c);
  leafValueMap = c.getLeafValues();
}

protected void doFlush() {
  checkObject();
  errors = new ArrayList<EditorError>();
  accept(new Flusher());
  accept(new ErrorCollector(errors));
}

//...
protected EditorVisitor createInitializerVisitor() {
  return new Initializer();
}
```

The `Initializer` extends `Refresher` which actually clears any dirty flags, but `Flusher` and `ErrorCollector` do not.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. But, I have called initialize() and edit() correctly. However, I am receiving null pointer exception at these statements.

Comment: If you are getting null pointers there, something else is wrong. Please post enough code in your question to describe the problem (since you never mentioned the NPE in your original question).